# Can I bake oatmeal drop cookies in a bar form?

Tags: cookies

I am making oatmeal cookies for a family get together and was wondering, can I make them as a bar cookie like as in chocolate chip, rather than a drop cookie.

Answer (score 2):

Most drop cookies that are made by creaming butter and sugar turn out fairly well as bar cookies.

One thing to think about is the additional baking time - since they are thicker, you may have an underdone center even once the top is golden brown.

You should probably bake them slightly longer than you would normally, and check them fairly frequently. I prefer my cookies chewy (almost like cookie dough) in the middle, so I tend to bake them for less time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes; just spread the dough in a well-greased pan.  I'd use a pan size such that the bars are not too much thicker than the cookies would be, or the cooking time/temperature will be trickier.

You will likely need to lower the oven temperature (I'd try 25 degrees cooler.) and bake for longer.  If you notice the edges browning and the center is still very raw, go ahead and turn the oven down a bit more.  Make sure to pull the pan from the oven when the center is not quite baked through, since it will continue to cook for a few minutes once it's out of the oven.